# css vs svg для создания простых изображений

Tags: html, jquery, css, svg, изображения

На странице требуется создать несколько (не больше сотни точно, скорее десяток) интерактивных рисунков (надписи и некоторые элементы могут быть кнопками/ссылками)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что  лучше использовать  `css` или `svg`.
Лично пока склоняюсь к `css + jQuery` для позиционирования элементов

Comment: вопрос несколько абстрактный... Все зависит от ситуации...  Мое мнение `svg` лучше...

Comment: Некоторые вещи которые на SVG делаются легко, нативно и понятно на CSS огромные и запутанные конструкции. Кроме того SVG предназначен для векторной графики, а у CSS совершенно другое предназначение.

Comment: проще, обычно, все деалть на css но по моему опыту, если элементы предполагают взаимодействие с пользователем (клики, ховеры и.т.п) лучше SVG. Но опять же все зависит от конкретной задачи

Comment: @Zhihar проще делать на том, что хорошо знаешь и умеешь делать. Знаете  отлично css, значит вам проще сделать на css. Если знаете хоть немного svg, то конечно проще на svg. Всего несколько строчек кода svg и никаких проблем с адаптивностью

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для графики, где много линий, кругов, фигур со сложными контурами лучше использовать `SVG`. *Графика должна быть векторной.*
 Не надо ставить вопрос,-  только `SVG` или только `CSS` и `JS` . Вся эта троица прекрасно дополняет друг друга.
В вашем примере, конечно лучше использовать `SVG`. Узоры повторяются, значит нужно использовать `pattern`, в который необходимо поместить одно звено цепи, а потом автоматически заполнять выбранный регион элементом паттерна. 
Заполнение паттерном идет по рядам, слева направо, после заполнения одного ряда, начинается заполнение следующего ряда.
Подробнее о svg патернах [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875) и [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns)

*Ниже пример кода для одного звена:*

```css
#bigCircle {
fill:none;
stroke:#3D6B93;
}
#leftCircle, #rightCircle  {

fill:#3D6B93;
} 

#centerCircle {
fill:#01AA4D;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
<pattern id="circleLine"   x="0" y="0" width="106" height="16"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
<g>
    <polyline points="16,8 107,8" stroke="#3D6B93" />

 

<circle id="bigCircle" cx="8" cy="8" r="7"  /> 
<circle id="centerCircle" cx="8" cy="8" r="2.5"   /> 
<circle id="leftCircle" cx="16" cy="8" r="2.5"  /> 
<circle id="rightCircle" cx="104" cy="8" r="2.5"  />
</g>
</pattern>
</defs> 

<rect y="16" width="106.5" height="16" stroke="none" fill="url(#circleLine)" /> 
</svg>
```

В секции `<defs>... </defs>` с помощью базовых фигур создаем элемент паттерна. 
Он не будет виден до тех пор пока мы не используем его для заполнения какой-то фигуры. Фигура внутри паттерна может иметь любые очертания, но она всегда заключена в прямоугольник, который должен быть не меньше габаритных размеров самой фигуры.
 В нашем случае размеры паттерна определяют    `width="106"` `height="16"`

Команда заполнения паттерном :

```
<rect y="16" width="106.5" height="16" stroke="none" fill="url(#circleLine)" />
```

Габаритные размеры прямоугольника равны размерам паттерна, поэтому разместилось одно звено.

Для увеличения количества звеньев просто увеличим ширину прямоугольника. Понятно, чтобы не было обрезки последней фигуры, необходима кратность размеров

*Пример с пятью звеньями*

```css
#bigCircle {
fill:none;
stroke:#3D6B93;
}
#leftCircle, #rightCircle  {

fill:#3D6B93;
} 

#centerCircle {
fill:#01AA4D;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 550 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
<pattern id="circleLine"   x="0" y="0" width="107" height="16"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
<g>
    <polyline points="16,8 107,8" stroke="#3D6B93" />

 

<circle id="bigCircle" cx="8" cy="8" r="7"  /> 

<circle cx="1" cy="8" r="2.5" fill="#3D6B93" /> 

<circle id="centerCircle" cx="8" cy="8" r="2.5"   /> 
<circle id="leftCircle" cx="16" cy="8" r="2.5"  /> 
<circle id="rightCircle" cx="108" cy="8" r="2.5"  />
</g>
</pattern>
</defs> 

<rect y="16" width="530" height="16" stroke="none" fill="url(#circleLine)" /> 
</svg>
```

И ещё один пример с многорядовым заполнением:

```css
#bigCircle {
fill:none;
stroke:#3D6B93;
}
#leftCircle, #rightCircle  {

fill:#3D6B93;
} 

#centerCircle {
fill:#01AA4D;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 550 150" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
<pattern id="circleLine"   x="0" y="0" width="107" height="16"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
<g>
    <polyline points="16,8 107,8" stroke="#3D6B93" />

 

<circle id="bigCircle" cx="8" cy="8" r="7"  /> 

<circle cx="1" cy="8" r="2.5" fill="#3D6B93" /> 

<circle id="centerCircle" cx="8" cy="8" r="2.5"   /> 
<circle id="leftCircle" cx="16" cy="8" r="2.5"  /> 
<circle id="rightCircle" cx="108" cy="8" r="2.5"  />
</g>
</pattern>
</defs> 

<rect y="16" width="530" height="128" stroke="none" fill="url(#circleLine)" /> 
</svg>
```

**Решение полностью адаптивно, работает во всех браузерах, включая `IE11`, `Edge`**

Comment: круто, а если некоторые из кругов должны быть ссылками по которым вызывается выполнение какой-нибудь js функции

или под кругом находится кнопка (хотя тут как я понимаю подойдет и чистый js который добавить <div> с нужными стилями

Comment: @Zhihar без проблем, ставите свойство pointer-events="none" и клик проходит сквозь фигуру на кнопку под узорами. Если мой ответ вам был полезен, не забудьте поставить плюс и чекбокс :)

Comment: лови плюсик, подробно описал, спасибо. Касательно второго вопроса "клик проходит сквозь фигуру на кнопку под узорами" - т.е. получается, что мне придётся все таки сгенерировать невидимые кнопки на уровне html (div например) и расположить их в нужном месте или можно отследить именно нажатие на конкретный svg элемент?

Comment: если бы я ее ещё видел :)